# Можно ли в AngularJS обрабатывать "абсолютные" URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vkontakte-api

Поясню: мне нужно сделать авторизацию через ВК. На определенном этапе авторизации, ВК должен перенаправить меня по определенному адресу, а я, в свою очередь, должен закончить авторизацию.

ВК нельзя заставить перенаправить пользователя по такому адресу:

> http://localhost:8000/#!/network-choose/auth/vk

А по такому можно:

> http://localhost:8000/network-choose/auth/vk

Вопрос - можно ли как-то заставить angular оперировать абсолютными путями, без "#!"?

Если нет, то как решить мою проблему?

Comment: [html5mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes)

Comment: @Grundy, на сколько я понял, это не универсальное решение. В документации написано, что если браузер пользователя не поддерживает этот режим, то будут использоваться обычные URL.

Comment: его поддерживаю все стабильные версии браузеров

Comment: ну и в любом случае - просто обработай на сервере данный урл и верни нужную страницу а дальше ангуляр

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По совету Grundy, пользуюсь [html5mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes).